# String search in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I'm creating a shell script to a basic program.

One option is to delete a user, but the problem is that if I search for a string that belongs to the username in question, the program will assume it as a user aswell.

For example, if I have the user adminaaa if I search for admin the program will recognize it as a user, even if "admin" is not a user.

The piece of code that I'm using is the following:

```
existe=`cat meusutilizadores.txt|grep "$user" |wc -l`
        if [ $existe = 1 ]
        then
            fullUser=`grep $user meusutilizadores.txt`
            passUser=$(echo $fullUser|awk -F ':' '{ print $2 }')
```

What I need is to be able to program it to recognize the user for his entire string, not only a part of it.

I hope I was able to express myself well enough for you to understand.
Hope you can help me.

Best regards

Comment: what is the format of the records in meusutilizadores.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for the whole term only:  `egrep "^${user}$"`

This won't work if `$user` contains regex special characters like `[]().*+`

Comment: Thank you very much, the user is still accepting special characters, I suppose I will have to change that because I really need this function to work. Thank you once again!